# Unit Testing - Basic Authentication: The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I am writing the test case for the BasicAuthenticationHandler but confused how should I implement it

```
public class BasicAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    private readonly BasicAuthenticationOptions _basicAuthOptions;
    private const string TOKEN_TYPE = "Basic";
    public BasicAuthenticationHandler(
       IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
       IOptions<BasicAuthenticationOptions> basicAuthOptions,       
       ILoggerFactory logger,
       UrlEncoder encoder,
       ISystemClock clock
    ) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock) {
        _basicAuthOptions = basicAuthOptions.Value;
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
       var token = Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault()?.Split().Last();

    }
}
```

BasicAuthenticationTests

```
public class BasicAuthenticationTests: BasicAuthenticationHandler
{
    public BasicAuthenticationTests(
      IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
      IOptions<BasicAuthenticationOptions> basicAuthOptions,
      ILoggerFactory logger,
      UrlEncoder encoder,
      ISystemClock clock
   ) : base(options, basicAuthOptions, logger, encoder, clock) { }

    [Fact]
    public void BasicAuthenticationTests_Valid_Request()
    {
        // arrange


        // act
        var results = base.HandleAuthenticateAsync();

        // assert
    }
}
```

While trying above code, i am getting
***The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: IOptionsMonitor'1 options, IOptions'1 _basicAuthOptions, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock***

also how should I set **Request.Headers["Authorization"]** in HandleAuthenticateAsync

Any suggestions would be helpful thank you in advance

Comment: You should create a spearate test class which is not inheriting from the original class. The test class should create an object of the original class and use the mocks of dependencies to pass to the constructor. you should set the behavior of the mocks and call methods on the class object to test their behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the response but i think there should be other way aswell trying few solutions

Comment: `BasicAuthenticationTests` is a constructor of test class and it has some parameters. The test framework is not able to find the values to pass to those parameters when initializing the test class object. The alternative you have is to have DI used (like service collection is used in the web application startup.cs file) in the test project, register all the dependencies in it and let test framework to use it to resolve the dependencies while creating the test class object.